# Alinhamento de div

Tags: html, css, div, layout-responsivo

Eu possuo uma tabela que é construída dinamicamente com as informações de um diretor de filme. E preciso mudar a estrutura para uma div, principalmente pela questão de responsabilidade, hoje ao reduzir o tamanho do componente que armazena essa table, o texto acaba se sobrepondo;

Hoje ela é assim:

```css
.label{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}

.blue-box{
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box">  
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="label">Nome:</td>
  <td>Del Toro</td>
  <td class="label">Data de cadastro:</td>
  <td>19/05/2017</td>
  <td class="label">Data de atualizacao:</td>
  <td>19/05/2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="label">Categoria de produto:</td>
  <td>Diverso</td>
  <td class="label">Ultimo Prêmio:</td>
  <td>Leão De Ouro</td>
  <td class="label">Filme Indicado</td>
  <td>Shape of Water</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>

</div>
```

Com div eu consegui fazer boa parte do trabalho, entretanto algumas coisas como o alinhamento presente nos labels eu não consegui fazer de jeito nenhum:

```css
.label{
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.blue-box{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.father{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px ;
}

.content{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box">  
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Nome:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Del Toro
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Data de cadastro:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    19/05/2017
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Data de atualizacao:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    19/05/2017
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Categoria de produto:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Diverso
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Ultimo Prêmio:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Leão de Ouro
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Filme indicado:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Shape of water
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Tem alguma forma de preservar esse alinhamento dos labels como se fosse na table apenas com HTML?

Ou vou ter que trabalhar com JS para tentar verificar a largura dos labels e setar como o maior elemento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrescente no .father

```
width:30%;
```

Veja se resolve o seu problema

```css
.label{
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.blue-box{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.father{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px ;
  width:30%;
}

.content{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box">  
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Nome:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Del Toro
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Data de cadastro:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    19/05/2017
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Data de atualizacao:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    19/05/2017
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Categoria de produto:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Diverso
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Ultimo Prêmio:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Leão de Ouro
  </div>
</div>
<div class="father">
  <div class="label">
  Filme indicado:
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Shape of water
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se deseja manter as dimensões das células como aconteceria com tables, trabalhar com o atributo CSS display pode resolver o seu problema.

Atributos display correspondentes aos elementos da tabela:

```
table { display : table}
tr { display : table-row}
thead { display : table-header-group }
tbody { display : table-row-group}
tfoot { display : table-footer-group }
col { display : table-column}
colgroup { display : table-column-group }
td, th { display :  table-cell }
caption { display : table-caption }
```

Fonte: [maujor.com](http://maujor.com/tutorial/anti-heroi-css-display-table.php)

Aplicado ao seu código ficaria assim:

```css
.label{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-right: 5px
}

.blue-box{
  background-color: aquamarine;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

.father{
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px ;
  display: table-row
}

.content{
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-box">
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Nome:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Del Toro
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Data de cadastro:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      19/05/2017
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Data de atualizacao:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      19/05/2017
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Categoria de produto:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Diverso
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Ultimo Prêmio:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Leão de Ouro
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="father">
    <div class="label">
      Filme indicado:
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Shape of water
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```